# Find the first element that is n times larger than current element in a list

Tags: list, algorithm, computer-science

It is easy to come up with an `O(n)` algorithm to solve this very famous question:

> For every element in the list, find the first element that is larger than it. This can be done using a stack. But, what if I want to find the first element that is larger than n*current element?

More specifically:

Given an array [2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 9, 6] and n = 2.

I want [5, -1, 9, -1, 8, -1, -1, -1]
For 2, 5 is the next element larger than n * 2, for 4, 9 is the next element larger than n * 4. For 5, there is no element larger than n * 5 so return -1 at that position.

Can we do better than `O(n^2)`?

Comment: your first problem is: For each element `a` find an element `b` that matches a predicate that depends on `a`. You know a `O(n)` algorithm to solve it. The second problem is: For each element `a` find an element `b` that matches a predicate that depends on `a`....

Comment: do you have a solution for the first? Then it should be not too difficult to adjust it. I don't know that "famous" problem, and I think you should not tag this as Java and C++, I wouldn't know what to write in the answer

Comment: `first element larger than it`: are u finding the first element larger than it in the remaining array right?

Comment: 2*3=6, and there is a 7 in the array, so why 8 as result?

Comment: Those look like the same problem to me. (Given a binary predicate P: for each element X in the list, find the first element Y such that P(X,Y) holds.)

Comment: @molbdnilo thats what I wanted to suggest with the first comment, maybe I was not clear enough. I don't see the difference

Comment: @idclev463035818 I read your comment too quickly.

Comment: This does look like the same problem. However, the stack-based solution doesn't allow a change in the predicate. The stack-based solution has rules for popping and pushing elements. Those operations maintain the stack invariant, which is that the elements on the stack are always in sorted order, with the top of the stack being the smallest. That invariant will not be maintained if the predicate is changed.

Comment: @molbdnilo I dont think the stack based solution is extendible if you now want to find the `>2x element`. You put in values in the stack based on the multiplier but your predicate is the same. Maybe you can try to replicate the stack-based solution for `>2x problem` and you will notice the limitations of it

Comment: @SerialLazer my critique about the question is that OP could/should have tried that or at least explain why it wont work instead of assuming that everybody is aware of why it doesn't work. But don't get me wrong, its a very mild critique, the question is fine, its just that I cannot contribute because it assumes something that I didn't know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with OP that, the simple predicate of the O(N) algo might not work on the stack-based solution when looking for the first element > 2x in the remaining array.

I found a O(NlogN) solution for this btw.

It uses a **Min-heap** to maintain the frontier elements we are interested in.

#### Pseudo-code:

```
def get_2x_elements(input_list, multipler = 2):
  H = [] #min-heap with node-values as tuples (index, value)
  R = [-1 for _ in range(len(input_list))] # results-list

  for index, value in enumerate(input_list):
    while multiplier*H[0][1] < value:
      minval = extractMinFromHeap(H)
      R[minval[0]] = value

  insertToMinHeap(H, (index, value))

  return R
```

#### Complexity-analysis:

```
1. Insertion/Extraction from min-heap = O(logN)
2. Number of such operations = N

Total-complexity = O(NlogN)
```

PS: This assumes we need the `first >2x element` from the remaining part of the list.

Re:
I made a Java verion implementation of your idea. Thanks @Serial Lazer

```java
    private static class ValueAndIndexPair implements Comparable<ValueAndIndexPair>{
        public final double value;
        public final int index;

        public ValueAndIndexPair(double value, int index) {
            this.value = value;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ValueAndIndexPair other) {
            return Double.compare(value, other.value);
        }
    }

    public static double[] returnNextNTimeLargerElementIndex(final List<Double> valueList, double multiplier) {
        double[] result = new double[valueList.size()];
        PriorityQueue<ValueAndIndexPair> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();

        // Initialize O(n)
        for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++) {
            result[i] = -1.0;
        }
        if (valueList.size() <= 1) return result;

        minHeap.add(new ValueAndIndexPair(valueList.get(0) * multiplier, 0));

        for (int i = 1; i <valueList.size(); i++) {
            double currentElement = valueList.get(i);
            while (!minHeap.isEmpty() && minHeap.peek().value < currentElement) {
                result[minHeap.poll().index] = currentElement;
            }
            minHeap.add(new ValueAndIndexPair(currentElement * multiplier, i));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I think I get you point, it is a beautiful usage of min heap. You maintained a min heap which holds those elements we visited but haven't find its next n* larger correspondant. For every new element, you extract the min from the heap one by one if the current element is n* larger than the min. You made a good use of the fact that "the smallest element always find the n* larger correspondant first"

Answer (score 0):

Sure, easily.

We just need a sorted version of the array (sorted elements plus their original index) and then we can do an efficient search (a modified binary search) that points us to the start of the elements that are larger than the current number (or a multiple of it, it doesn't matter). Those elements we can then search sequentially for the one with the smallest index (that is greater than the one of the current number, if so required).

Edit: It was pointed out that the algorithm may not be better than O(n²) because of the sequential search of the elements that satisfy the condition of being greater. This may be so, I'm not sure.
But note that we may build a more complex search structure that involves the index already, somehow. This is left as homework. :)

Comment: This wouldn't be better than ```O(N^2)```

Comment: @AbhinavMathur: It would be `O(N log N)` which is better than `O(N²)`.

Comment: `Those elements we can then search sequentially for the one with the smallest index ` This will make the complexity O(N^2)

Comment: Unless of course you have a smart way to reduce this to O(NlogN)

Comment: Consider a list which is already sorted in ascending order. To find the minimum index, you'll traverse till the end each time, making it ```N-1 + N-2 ... = O(N^2)```

Comment: @AbhinavMathur: No, you don't have to restart from beginning, but from previous index, so it is `O(2*n)` (one for input, one for output).

Comment: @AbhinavMathur If the searched element doesnt exist, we dont need any sequential search at all. And in the rest of the cases maybe only half as much (on average). So I guess it is slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

The stack-based solution [offered at geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/) does not seem to maintain the order of the elements in the result even in its output:

```
input: int arr[] = { 11, 13, 21, 3 };
output: 
 11 -- 13
 13 -- 21
 3 -- -1
 21 -- -1
```

After minor modification to find the first element which is greater N times than a current, this algorithm fails to detect 9 for the element 4 from the given example.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/SXM7j4)

```
input: int arr[] = { 2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 9, 6 }; // as in this question
output: 
2 * 2 --> 5
2 * 3 --> 8
6 -- -1
9 -- -1
8 -- -1
7 -- -1
4 -- -1
5 -- -1
```

Thus, initial assumption about existing solution with complexity O(N) is not quite applicable to the expected result.